# Snowflake Snowsql !source tab complete

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

Is there a way to enable tab or some other auto-complete when using Snowflake's Snowsql cli?

I keep having to copy and paste the entire file path whenever running a script from the command line.

`[USER]#(Analytics_WH)@PROD.(data_white)>!source [file_name]`

Comment: I am running into the same issue, I started putting the files in the same folder, and them hitting the up arrow to minimize the need for changing the entire file path.  There might be a better way though.

Comment: I created a snowflake community idea on your behalf here: "Autocomplete filepath for Snowsql directory", please feel free to follow this in the Snowflake Community https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas